# remove graphics from inside a class as3

Tags: class, actionscript-3, flash, graphics

When I click a button in my game it draws shapes using the graphics in as3. simple shapes such as circles and rectangles.

I want to remove the graphics that have been drawn when something happens in one of my classes.

Basically when there is a hitTestObject (which works fine) I want all graphics on stage to be cleared.

```
if (gb2.hitTestObject(h1s2))
            {
                trace ("holed")
                ySpeed2=0;
                xSpeed2=0;
                this.visible=false;


                var mcSplash:MovieClip =parent.getChildByName("mcSplash") as MovieClip;
                mcSplash.visible=true;
                //parent.drawings.graphics.clear();
            }
```

My attempt using parent.drawings.graphics.clear(); was unsuccessful, it gives me this error:

Line 481   1119: Access of possibly undefined property drawings through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObjectContainer.

Anyone have any suggestions

UPDATE:

this is how, on the min time line, the drawings occur.

```
var drawings:Shape = new Shape;

for (i=0; i<numRecs; i++) 


{

    recStartX = Number(xmlContent.rec[i].startpoint.@ptx);

    recStartY = Number(xmlContent.rec[i].startpoint.@pty);

    recWidth = Number(xmlContent.rec[i].dimensions.@w);

    recHeight = Number(xmlContent.rec[i].dimensions.@h);

    fillColor=int(xmlContent.rec[i].look.fillhex);

    lineThick = Number(xmlContent.rec[i].look.strokethick);

    lineColor = int(xmlContent.rec[i].look.strokehex);

    drawings.graphics.lineStyle(lineThick, lineColor);

    drawings.graphics.beginFill(fillColor);

    drawings.graphics.drawRect(recStartX,recStartY,recWidth,recHeight);

    drawings.graphics.endFill();

}
```

Comment: My initial guess is that `drawings` doesn't exist in the parent. Try debugging your application to find out what `parent` is actually referencing and whether it's also the parent of `drawings`.

Comment: Check the edit above sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array and push in each shape/rect.
Then iterate through this and remove..

```
for(var iteration:int = 0; iteration < rectArray.length; iteration++)
    this.removeChild(rectArray[iteration]);
```

or if you are calling this from a class, use

```
MovieClip(this.root).removeChild(rectArray[iteration]);
```

Hopefully this is helpful :)
Z

Answer (score 0):

What's `drawings`?! If you draw in mcSplash, you should use `mcSplash.graphics.clear()`. If you draw in a child called `drawings`, you should first get it as a child (after mcSplash get): `var drawings = mcSplash.getChildByName('drawings); drawings.graphics.clear();`. You could write checks to see what's going on: `if (mcSlpash) { if (drawings) {`, etc..

Comment: drawings is a variable in the main timeline code that draws the new shapes:-
    var drawings:Shape=new Shape();

Comment: This is still not enough, as we don't know what `parent` is - you haven't specified where this code is executed. If `mcSplash` is found, then `drawings` should be __at the same level__ as `mcSplash`, or it won't be found. Just fix the paths - use `trace(child)` if you can't use breakpoints..

Comment: forget parent, its nothing. It was just my attempt to make the graphics disappear. I just need the graphics drawn in the main timeline action script to be removed when the event happens inside a class

Comment: Any other suggestions guys?